# Are there signification health risks with long term use of headphones on a cellphone?

Tags: mobile-phones

Does using headphones / earphones plugged into a cellphone for taking calls / listening to music pose a significant health risk in the long run in terms of radiation exposure?

> Also it depends what your headphones are connected to. If they are
>   connected to your cell phone and you are taking calls using a wired
>   headset your exposure could be significant. A conventional headset
>   uses a wire cable. Wire has metal in it. This metal conducts the
>   radiation coming from your cell phone allowing it to travel up the
>   wire and into your head.
>
> What about just listening to music on your cell phone. If the music is
>   downloaded onto your phone this is safer. But if you are streaming,
>   then again your EMF exposures could be significant.

http://elynjacobs.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/are-your-headphones-an-emf-health-risk/

Based on Konrad's comment, a link to the Bioinitiative Report: 
http://www.bioinitiative.org/table-of-contents/
The relevant sections appears to be Section6, Section9, Section10, Section11 and Section13 (I still need to read through these, will quote sections out of these as I work through them)

Counter arguments:

> CONCLUSIONS: Our results showed no evidence of any association between
>   ELF-MF exposure (100 µT at 50 Hz) and AD, and ELF-MF exposure does not
>   influence the pathogenesis of AD induced by Al overload.
>
> [Neurological Effects of Non-Ionizing
>   Electromagnetic Fields](http://www.bioinitiative.org/report/wp-content/uploads/pdfs/sec09_2012_Evidence_%20Effects_%20%20Neurology_behavior.pdf)

Comment: I think I have heard similar claims in the past, but it wouldn't be a bad idea to link to something a bit more notable than a blogger, so we know it is widely believed, not just one person's misunderstanding.

Comment: Will do a bit more digging

Comment: You can link to the source of these bogus claims, the BioInitiative Report, directly. That said, it’s not hard to find good sources which pick holes in the report.

Comment: This can be disproved by attacking the core argument that cell phone radiation poses a threat, which has already been done very thoroughly.