# Do Bluetooth headsets pose any health risks?

Tags: medical-science, safety

What's the current state of knowledge concerning health risks caused by Bluetooth headsets?

What has been confirmed so far?

I lack the expertise to evaluate which reports are trustworthy and which are not.

> Additionally, some people may suffer from hypersensitivity to the
>   microwave radio frequencies, causing them to get headaches just from
>   turning a phone on or being in a room with someone on a phone or
>   headset. According to the United States Food and Drug Administration,
>   the US Federal Communications Commission, and the United Kingdom
>   National Radiological Protection Board, all available scientific
>   research shows that mobile devices are safe, but further research is
>   necessary. ([Source](http://www.wisegeek.org/do-bluetooth-headsets-cause-cancer.htm))

Comment: Is this question conformant with the site's format, given the fact that no pieces of previous study or research or effort is provided?

Comment: @JasonStack *questions* need to be about notable claims, but there's no need to bring proof. On the other hand, it's clear that if a question is notable (i.e. if a lot of people believe that), then it should be trivial to find examples via a [simple google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bluetooth+health+risks).

Comment: @JasonStack: Tried to make the question more conformant by providing a direct quote.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the other wifi/bluetooth/cellphone microwave safety questions?

Comment: Microwave horns/dishes on towers apparently aren't killing workers, despite stories:  http://www.snopes.com/horrors/techno/microwave.asp

Comment: @Paul: I wouldn't say it was a duplicate because this one is specifically about Bluetooth radiation. Or is it so that WiFi, Bluetooth and cellphone wavelenghts are so similar that its pratically the same?

Comment: From the spectrum chart you included, below, WiFi and Bluetooth both operate in the 2.4Ghz band.  Cellphones use a lower frequency that is still considered low frequency microwaves. The types of electromagnetic waves are very similar.  One can argue about which is closest to your head, the typical duration, or whether there are other dangers.  For instance, a headset of any type may distract you or break into sharp pieces during an impact (e.g. automobile crash with airbag deployment; bicycling/motorcycle accidents)

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/are-wifi-waves-harmful

Answer (score 9):

After some googling, this seems to be the current state of knowledge, which is not specifically about Bluetooth headsets but wireless electronic devices in general:

- No negative effects of short-term use were found
- Research on effects of long-term use hasn't been done yet or is in progress, respectively

**My sources**

*Trustworthy*

- Bluetooth uses the wave spectrum between 2.402 GHz and 2.480 GHz
- Image source: http://theconversation.com/wireless-spectrum-is-for-sale-but-what-is-it-11794
  [image]
- [Do mobile phones have anything to do with brain cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/569/do-mobile-phones-have-anything-to-do-with-brain-cancer)

*Seem trustworthy*

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Health_concerns
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_electronic_devices_and_health
- [Do cellphone towers cause health issues?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20001/do-cellphone-towers-cause-health-issues?rq=1)
- [Are there signification health risks with long term use of headphones on a cellphone?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22127/are-there-signification-health-risks-with-long-term-use-of-headphones-on-a-cellp)
- [Does home-WiFi expose you to less radiation than using the 3G on your cell-phone?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/does-home-wifi-expose-you-to-less-radiation-than-using-the-3g-on-your-cell-phone/4152?s=1|0.0547#4152)

*Don't know whether it's trustworthy*

- https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120321034840AALrBGt